Separable decomposition $F(r,\theta) = A(r) + B(\theta)$
Is it possible in Mathematica to take a function $F(r, \theta)$ and ask it to rewrite it as $F(r,\theta) = A(r) + B(\theta)$? In particular, I have the expression:
$$ \frac{g^{2} (r) f^{2} (r) \sin^{2} \theta}{a g^{2}(r) f^{2}(r) \sin^{2} \theta + b h(r) f^{2}(r) \sin^{2} \theta - d^{2} g^{2} (r)} = A(r) + B(\theta)$$
where $a$, $b$ and $d$ are constants. Could someone guide me or is there a way to know if it is possible or not without having to try it by hand until it is achieved or, failing that, not? The Mathematica code for the above function is as follows:
F[r, \[Theta]] = ((g^2)[r] *(f^2)[r] *(Sin[\[Theta]])^2)/(
  a*(g^2)[r]*(f^2)[r]*(Sin[\[Theta]])^2 + 
   b*h[r]*(f^2)[r]*(Sin[\[Theta]])^2 - d^2*(g^2)[r]);


Not all functions can be so decomposed, e.g., $F(r, \theta) = r \cdot \theta$.  See Collect.

This is not possible. Set $\theta$ to 0. $F(r,0)=0\Rightarrow A(r)=0.$

I’m voting to close this question because there is no solution.

I'm not aware that a Mathematica could check this conditions. Maybe some neat trick using Collect could do, this is more of a of a mathematical question.
But anyway, we can test whether a function is a separable by a test. Assuming that the function smooth enough (for details see this article), the "separation test" is
$$
F(r,\theta) \frac{ \partial^2 F(r, \theta)}{\partial r \partial \theta} =  \frac{ \partial F(r, \theta)}{\partial r } \frac{ \partial F(r, \theta)}{\partial \theta}
$$
this works out to be
$$
2 a g(r)^3 f'(r)+b g(r) \left(2 h(r) f'(r)+f(r) h'(r)\right)-2 b f(r) h(r) g'(r) = 0
$$
So your function is probably not separable.
Note:
If you want to define a function, use F[r_,\[Theta]_]=$\dots$ instead of F[r,\[Theta]], also in Mathematica, the notation for a square of function $f(r)$ is f[r]^2 not f^2[r].

Thank you very much for the reference and suggestion!

You omit the condition $F(r,\theta)\neq 0$.

Yes, among other conditions.
